# repmgr - how to make previous Primary to become a standby after failover

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

After performing a fail over, I had the previous Primary down, and the old standby became the Primary, as expected.

```
$  repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show --compact
ID | Name            | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Prio. | TLI

----+-----------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+-----

1  | server1         | primary | - failed  |          | default  | 100   | ?

2  | server2         | primary | * running |          | default  | 100   | 2

3  | PG-Node-Witness | witness | * running | server2  | default  | 0     | 1
```

I would like to make the old Primary join the cluster as a standby.

I gather the rejoin command should do that.

However, when I try to rejoin it, to be the new standby, I get this (I run this on the old Primary which is down ):

```
repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf -d 'host=10.9.7.97 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr' node rejoin
```

--where 10.9.7.97 is the ip of node I am running from.

I get this error:

```
$ repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf -d 'host=10.97.7.97 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr' node rejoin  --verbose -
NOTICE: using provided configuration file "/etc/repmgr.conf"
ERROR: connection to database failed
DETAIL:
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.97.7.97" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Of course postgres is down on 10.9.7.97 - the old primary.

If I start it however, it starts as another primary:

```
$  repmgr -f /etc/repmgr.conf cluster show --compact

 ID | Name            | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Prio. | TLI

----+-----------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+-------+-----

 1  | server1         | primary | ! running |          | default  | 100   | 1

 2  | server2         | primary | * running |          | default  | 100   | 2

 3  | PG-Node-Witness | witness | * running | server2  | default  | 0     | 1
```

- so what is the way to make the old primary the new standby...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the

```
-d 'host=
```

in the rejoin command, should specify the current Primary (previous standby).

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue resolved with the `-d 'host='` corrected as suggested above?

Based on my experience, in case an old Primary shutdown, it cannot startup automatically, instead we must use the repmgr node rejoin command to bring the old primary into cluster as an new standby.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cluster is configured with data checksums or `wal_log_hints` is enabled you can use `pg_rewind` to rejoin the cluster:

```
repmgr node rejoin -f /etc/repmgr.conf \
-d 'host=primary.example.com dbname=repmgr user=repmgr' \
--force-rewind --verbose --dry-run
```

(without the `--dry-run` flag, if you know what you're doing).